# What to do to make loop ignore empty directories

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu, unix

I have a loop and I need it to ignore empty directories.

```
for i in */*/
do

    cd "$i"
    mv ./*.py ..
    cd -
    rm -r "$i"
done
```

What can i add on to make it ignore empty directories?

I have this but I would like something simpler

```
    x=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; echo "$i"/*)
    (( ${#x} )) || continue
```

Comment: By "ignore" empty directories, do you mean that not only should it not attempt to move `.py` files out of them, but also it should not attempt to remove them?

Comment: By the way, that `rm -r "$i"` gives me the shivers.

Answer (score 0):

> What can i add on to make it ignore empty directories?

Bash does not have a primitive operator for testing whether a directory is empty.  The best alternative in your case is probably to test whether pathname expansion matches any files within. That's what you are already considering, though I would write it differently.

As a general rule, I would also avoid changing the working directory.  If you *must* change directory then consider doing it in a subshell, so that you need only let the subshell terminate to revert to the original working directory.  Using a subshell is also a good approach when different parts of your script want different shell options.

I would probably write your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob dotglob

for i in */*/; do
  anyfiles=( "$i"/* )
  if [[ ${#anyfiles[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    # Process nonempty directory "$i"

    # If there are any Python files within then move them to the parent directory
    pyfiles=( "$i"/*.py )
    if [[ ${#pyfiles[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
      mv "${pyfiles[@]}" "$(dirname "$i")"
    fi

    # Remove directory "$i" and any remaining contents
    rm -r "$i"
  fi
done
```

If you want that as part of a larger script, then you could put everything from the `shopt` to the end in a subshell to limit the scope of the `shopt`.

Alternatively, you could simplify that slightly at the cost of some clarity by using loops to skip the capture of the directory contents into explicit variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob dotglob

for i in */*/; do
  for anyfile in "$i"/*; do
    # Process nonempty directory "$i"

    # If there are any Python files within then move them to the parent directory
    for pyfile in "$i"/*.py; do
      mv "$i"/*.py "$(dirname "$i")"
      break
    done

    # Remove directory "$i" and any remaining contents
    rm -r "$i"

    break
  done
done
```

In that case, each inner loop contains an unconditional `break` at the end, so at most one iteration will be performed.